# Powershell script to map drives, persistent connection not working

Tags: powershell, mapped-drive

The code below allows me to map the appropriate network drives as and when needed.

The problem I have is when I restart the computer, the mapped drives are lost. So I need to run the script again.

```
$Net = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network  
$Rename = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application

#### # Map the network drives
$Net.MapNetworkDrive("A:", '\\192.168.1.10\NAS1\Automate')
$Net.MapNetworkDrive("G:", '\\10.0.0.1\NAS1\VidePro')  

timeout 4

#### # Rename everything
Write-Host "Naming all mapped driver correctly"
$rename.NameSpace("A:\").Self.Name = 'AutoMate 1Gbit' 
$rename.NameSpace("G:\").Self.Name = 'VidPro 10Gbit'
```

I have tried the following pieces of code unfortunately it does not work:

```
$Net.MapNetworkDrive("A:", '\\192.168.1.10\NAS1\Automate' -Persist)
$Net.MapNetworkDrive("A:", '\\192.168.1.10\NAS1\Automate' -Persistant)
$Net.MapNetworkDrive("A:", '\\192.168.1.10\NAS1\Automate', -Persist)
$Net.MapNetworkDrive("A:", '\\192.168.1.10\NAS1\Automate' '-Persist'
```

I am not sure what I am missing here.

Just as a side note. There are no credentials in the above script as I usually log in and to the credentials first and then run the script. Just an extra security measure on my behalf.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$NPSDArgs = @{Name       = "A" 
              PSProvider = "FileSystem"
              root       = "\\192.168.1.10\NAS1\Automate" 
              Persist    = $True
             }

New-PSDrive @NPSDargs
```

To remove the drive:

```
Remove-PSDrive -Name "A"
```

HTH

Comment: Festival think you very much for the information. I have a question. Can this fitting one line. Because I have many drives that I need to map?

Comment: For example: ```New-PSDrive Name = "A", PSProvider = "FileSystem", root = "\\192.168.1.10\NAS1\Automate", Persist = $True``` The reason I would like to have as a single line is that I have many drives to map.

Comment: I also tired: ```New-PSDrive -Name A FileSystem -Root \\192.168.1.10\NAS1\Automate -PSProvider -Scope Global```

Comment: Arthor, if you have a lot of drives to map you could place the Name and Root in a hash table or array and just loop through it.

Comment: I would love to. But I am not at you level thus far. However, I do have this would not... I only have 7 drive to map. 

```New-PSDrive -Name A FileSystem -Root \\192.168.1.10\NAS1\automate –Persist -Scope Global```

I think everything is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Arthor,

Here's how to do it in a loop:

```
$MapTable = @{
  "A" = "\\192.168.1.10\NAS1\Automate"
  "B" = "\\192.168.1.11\NAS2\Automate"
  "H" = "\\192.168.1.12\NAS3\Automate"
}

$MapTable.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {

  $NPSDArgs = @{Name       = "$($_.Key)" 
                PSProvider = "FileSystem"
                root       = "$($_.Value)" 
                Persist    = $True
               }
  
  New-PSDrive @NPSDargs -WhatIf

} #End ForEach-Obj...
```

Remove the -WhatIf when you are sure it does what you want.

WhatIf output:

What if: Performing the operation "New drive" on target "Name: B Provider: Micro
soft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem Root: \192.168.1.11\NAS2\Automate".

What if: Performing the operation "New drive" on target "Name: A Provider: Micro
soft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem Root: \192.168.1.10\NAS1\Automate".

What if: Performing the operation "New drive" on target "Name: H Provider: Micro
soft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem Root: \192.168.1.12\NAS3\Automate".

You'll note that the output is not in the same order as the MapTable. This is a "feature" of Hash tables. If you want the output in the same order use the [ordered] decorator on the definition of the table, e.g. $MapTable = [ordered]@{...}.

HTH

Comment: Thank you.. I will try this out!